# changing user role in drupal

Tags: drupal

I want to change the role of registered user to administrator. how do i do this?

-Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why is that?!? there is another approach if i understand you well, you have to create new role called superuser or what so ever, and give that role full permission, and then assign that user to this role, then you are done..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://drupal.org/node/66559) will help.  There's also a module called AdminRole that addresses the issues that post mentions- it automatically gives a user with the newly installed "AdminRole" all administrative roles from modules installed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is made easier in Drupal 7. It comes with "Administrator" role which can be assigned to any user when needed.
Just edit the user profile page & check the  "Administrator" checbox.